# Посоветуйте модуль по работе с ms excel документами  без установленного пакета

Tags: excel, visual-c++

**Доброго времени суток**!

Есть необходимость читать и писать данные в **MS Excel** документы без использования пакета **MS OFFICE**. Нашли стороннюю либу, но к сожалению, она под старый формат (xls), да и дикие утечки памяти с ее стороны. Бонусом проблем является ограничения формата документа в 65к строк и падения при нехватки ОЗУ. Вообще дико кушает память, аж волосы колосятся.

---

**PS:** Будет использоваться в коммерческом приложении, рассмотрятся платные варианты компонентов.

**Заранее - спасибы.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для работы с xlsx-документами, как и вообще с документами Office 2007 и выше используется [OpenXML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/office/bb448854(v=office.14).aspx) Правда, я не в курсе о возможности его взаимодействтия с C++, но  если будете использовать C#, то проблем не возникнет.

Comment: Спасибо, мне как тестеру-руководителю проекта эта информация очень полезна :-) Сам "кодю" на шарпе, но руководитель разработки не хочет тащить framework ради пару фитч, которых за пяток лет накопилось уйма.
Попробую поискать в этом направление информации по портированию в vc++. Или дрючить обормотов-прогеров, пусть сами развиваются, гуглят. А то ответы, типа "это нельзя, потому что невозможно, я искал" меня абсолютно не устраивают.

Comment: возможно стоит попробовать через C++/CLI, хотя я с ним не знаком